# search and replace file text with code with single quotes inside python string

Tags: python, django

I'm have with a question in the last two days.
I'm trying search and replace part of text file with single quotes, bur I'm receiving an error. log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./vhost.py", line 194, in <module>
    """.format(db_name=_db_name, db_user=_db_user,db_pass=_db_pass, db_host=_db_host)
KeyError: "\n        'default'"
```

I think the problem are in **'default'"**

The code:

```
if _create_database == "Y" or _create_database == "y":
    _backendmysql = """
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
            'NAME': '{db_name}',
            'USER': '{db_user}',
            'PASSWORD': '{db_pass}',
            'HOST': '{db_host}',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
            #'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
    """.format(db_name=_db_name, db_user=_db_user,db_pass=_db_pass, db_host=_db_host)

    _backendsqlite = '''
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
    '''

    try:
      with fileinput.FileInput(strSettingsPath, inplace=True, backup=None) as file:
          for line in file:
              print(line.replace(bytes(_backendsqlite, 'UTF-8'), bytes(_backendmysql, 'UTF-8') , end=''))
    except Exception as e:
      raise e
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your query is a string literal, so when it's trying to parse this it thinks your "key" is newline, 8 spaces, 'default' when you just want your key to be 'default' -- if you want to do multi-line indented pretty format, you need a dictionary so Python understands the continuation structure

Comment: how I do this? put code in a dict{} ? please give an example